# What is the difference between syntax : | / for lmer models with interactions and nesting due to rank deficiency?

Tags: r, nested, lme4, anova, mixed-models

I conceptually understand the difference between interactions, nested effects, etc. But I am confused about how to specify them properly in `ANOVA` models. I mostly work with `lme4::lmer` mixed models. Many posts in this forum use several terms for interactions and nested effects, and some are said to be interchangeable. An excellent explanation was provided by Robert Long at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified

`*`, `:`, `|`, and `/`. But in my experience trying to use them, they do not behave interchangeably. Can someone who really understands `R` syntax please clarify the meaning of these symbols in the context of mixed models?

Here is a more complex example model with interactions and nesting that I am having troubles with.

Given four fixed-effect factors `c(A,B,C,D)`, where `A*B*C` are crossed factorially. `D` is nested within the interaction of `B*C` because `D` is rank deficient, otherwise it would also be factorial. Please note that in my case, the nested interaction is not coded uniquely. The data was set up to be a 4-way factorial. There is also a random-effect `R` that is a time-based replication.

```
fit0 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) ? (D?B?C) + (1|R) + (1|R:A:B:C:D)
anova(fit0, ddf="Kenward-Roger")   

#Design structure expects 9 fixed terms
A
B
C
A:B
A:C
B:C
A:B:C
D nested in (B*C) (this is the problem term) --> x
A:x
```

I have tried different symbols to make the nested interaction `x`, but none are correct to the data structure or the model fails to converge. For example:

```
fit1 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) + (D:B:C) ...)   #Same as ...+ (B:C/D)
#All variation from main effects of B and C are partitioned into x
#anova has 8 levels, is missing level A:x

fit2 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) + (B/C/D) ...)   
#Variation partitions mostly correct, but ddf for F-tests are not correct
#anova has 10 levels, gives D, D:B, D:B:C, missing A:x

fit3 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) + (D|B|C) ...)   
#Error in model.matrix.default(eval(substitute(~foo, list(foo = x[[2]]))),  : 
  model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()

fit4 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) * (D:B:C) ...)  
#All variation from main effects of B and C are partitioned into x
#anova has 9 "correct" terms

fit5 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) + (D:B*C) ...)
#Variation mostly partitions correctly, but ddf for F-tests are not correct
#anova has 8 terms, D:B, D:B:C, missing A:x

fit6 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) + (D:(B*C)) ...)
#Variation mostly partitions correctly, but ddf for F-tests are not correct
#anova has 10 levels, D:B, D:C, D:B:C, missing A:x

fit6 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) * (D:(B:C)) ...)
#All variation from all effects of B and C are partitioned into x, ddf for F-tests are not correct
#anova has 10 levels, D:B, D:C, D:B:C, missing A:x

fit7 = lmer(y = (A) * (B) * (C) + (D|B*C) ...)   
#Model fails to converge.
```

A second question is what if I wanted analyze the same model, but `D` was a random effect. For example, `(1|D:B*C)` no longer executes because of `*`.

I would appreciate help getting the syntax sorted out. Thanks!